# Using the subprocess or Command module of python for Windows command prompt

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I am learning python and am watching the google classes to get started. I have some problems with the 3rd assignment. We are supposed to find special file from a directory and the copy or zip them by giving commands to the command prompt line.

This is what the function that copies files looks like:

```
def copy(dir,todir):    
    filenames=os.listdir(dir)

    for file in filenames:
       cmd='copy'+' '+file+' '+todir 
       print(cmd)
       (status,output)=subprocess.getstatusoutput(cmd) 
         print(output)
    return
```

The error says that

```
'{' not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

The subprocess.getstatusoutput method adds a '{' and a few other things to the cmd before sending it to os.popen().

I am hoping to see a 'x Files copied' as an output.

I am using Windows 8.

Any idea as to what the problem is? Could it be because of the OS? Any idea about how to fix it?

The videos use python2.7 and I am using python3.2 where the command module is replaced by subprocess module. Are the getstatusoutput methods in both the same?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/subprocess.html) says:
*cmd is actually run as*:

```
{ cmd ; } 2>&1
```

And the function `getstatusoutput()` is available on UNIX not on Windows.

Comment: Give a try for the following:         `process = subprocess.Popen( cmd + params,
            shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=False)` and get the output 
        `out = process.stdout.read()`